# How to use zend Filter to filter particular string from a text box, in zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am using zend Form  for creating the form.
Now i need to filter a particular value coming from the text boxes.
How can i use zend_filter or any other method for this purpose

For example;

I have text box called 'name' ,with default value 'First Name'.

After form submit, i need to get the value for 'name' field, so that it don't contain 'First Name' string

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying in the question, that you want to filter the text "First Name".

Why are you put that text default? If you want to show that in the `textbox` then you can use the `Placeholder`. [Here is the full implementation of it](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder).

It will surly solve your problem.

Here is the [example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder).

Here is the mootool code, mootool is the library of JS:

```
var firstNameBox = $('first_name'),
    message = firstNameBox.get('placeholder');
firstNameBox.addEvents({
    focus: function() {
        if(firstNameBox.value == message) { searchBox.value = ''; }
    },
    blur: function() {
        if(firstNameBox.value == '') { searchBox.value = message; }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But The placeholder attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

Comment: @LintoPD check the link there is a JS that is used to support the placeholder in IE.

Comment: Heart  i can't find the Js